# Получение данных с помощью Request.QueryString.

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Добрый день коллеги разработчики!
Столкнулся с такой проблемой ниже будет много кода, для удобства всех участников обсуждения:
Есть код на одной странице

```
    //тут page_load ( убран )

    protected void SearchNavigate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    // Это поиск айдишника в базе
        var searchText = MotorSearch.Text;

        var id = new PassportWheelsetManager().GetByAxisNumber(searchText).Return(x => x.Id, (Guid?) null);

        if (id != null)
            IdKp = (Guid) id;
        else
            IdKp = Guid.Empty;

        NaznachenieLabels();
    }
    public Guid IdKp
    {
        get { return ViewState["DataAboutKp"] != null ? (Guid) ViewState["DataAboutKp"] : Guid.Empty; }
        set { ViewState["DataAboutKp"] = value; }
    }
   //тут код запроса данных в базе по айдишнику

    #endregion LogikaPoiska

    #region NumbersQuery

    public class Numbers
    {
        public string AxisNumber { get; set; }
        //далее несколько аналогичных строк кода
    }

    public class NumbersQuery : CustomEntityManager
    {
        public Numbers GetData(Guid idKp)
        {
            return (fr om wheelset in GetAll<PassportWheelset>()
                   //Тут тело запроса

                    where wheelset.Id == idKp

                    select new Numbers
                        {
                            AxisNumber = axisnumber,
                            //Тут несколько аналогичных строк 
                        })
                .SingleOrDefault();
        }
    }

    #endregion NumbersQuery

    #region LogikaPageLoad

    private void NaznachenieLabels()
    {
    //тут назначение данных элементам на самой странице 
        #region Numbers

        var numbers = new NumbersQuery().GetData(IdKp);

        var resultnumbers = numbers != null;

        NumberAxic.Text = resultnumbers ? numbers.AxisNumber : "";
        //Тут несколько аналогичных строк

        #endregion Numbers

    #endregion LogikaPageLoad

    #region EventHendler

    protected void PrintData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    //передача данных на другую страницу
        var dataaboutid = IdKp.ToString();
        Response.Redirect("~/Journals/JournalsDataOKp/PrintDataAboutMotorKP.aspx?dataaboutid=" + dataaboutid);
    }

    #endregion EventHendler

}
```

все успешно работает на этой странице данные загружаются куда надо , но на другой странице куда я передаю данные все в принципе аналогично, отличается одним методом ( страница где печатаются данные с первой страницы ) но там табличка не заполняется я думаю так думаю что из-за того что я не верно получаю данные

```
    public void Polucenieid()
    {
        var id = Request.QueryString["dataaboutid"];
        if (id != null) IdKp = new Guid(id);
        NaznachenieLabels();
    }
```

Помогите разобраться где я не прав и что я не так делаю )

Comment: Звучит очевидным, но.. просто проверьте значение `Request.QueryString["dataaboutid"]` в дебаге.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К сожалению не могу выложить скриншоты, сразу бы стало все понятно, вообще идея еще раз проверить дебагом была хорошей, однако до этого я проверял только первую строчку метода, сейчас проверил обе, как результат имеем следующее: `Request.QueryString["dataaboutid"];` как и ожидалось, выдавал результат нормальный, проблема была в назначении `Guid`, id был null, ReSharper при написании метода подсовывал проверку на null как результат IdKp становился вида `0000-0000-0000-0000`,оставив только обратное прямое преобразование (`IdKp = new Guid(id);`) все заработало!